# What are the improvements of JGraphX vs JGraph 5

Tags: java, swing, jgraphx, jgraph

I read on a lots of posts saying that JGraphX corresponds to version 6 of JGraph. They changed the name because they rewrote all the code from scratch....Ok !

I'm using JGraph 5 and I downloaded JGraphX and I looked a little bit the "new" code but for me it look the same as the JGraph 5 code....

So my question is : What are the improvements of JGraphX vs JGraph 5 ? For what reasons/issues they rewrite all the codes ?

Thx for your answers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a rewrite of JGraph 5. That is an large effort in time and energy not being paid, so one may assume that it was worthwile. Of course they kept the API the same, so rewrite errors (so-called regression errors) can be found easily. Maybe at some points the library is faster, as code and data structures were thought over.

Comment: We didn't keep the API the same, thus the name change, rather than just a version number change.